# Will it be possible to use Apache CXF with Quarkus, with native compilation?

Tags: cxf, quarkus

I was wondering if it would be possible to use Apache CXF with Quarkus, with a native compilation, any pros or cons ?

Comment: It is definitely theoretically possible! I would imagine one would need to do things similar to what has been done in the RESTEasy Quarkus extension.

Answer (score 1):

you can found quarkus extension here.
https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkiverse-cxf
You can used it with maven central.

Comment: See also the docs at https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-cxf/dev/index.html

Answer (score 0):

It is under development. Track progress at this ticket: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/4005